# How to check if any row is more than x and return name of column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe of id, col1,col2,col3,col4 as it is described on picture.

I want to write function which find if any row is more than x an return name of column in which this condition was true and return it in result column.

```
userid  col1    col2    col3    col4    result
d1  40  50  75  65  col3
d2  54  20  61  71  col4
d3  12  75  12  60  col2
d4  75  12  14  16  col1
```

[image: See Image]

Comment: What if multiple columns will contain value > x what do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `idxmax` with `(axis=1)` to work on columns :

```py
>>> df[['col1','col2','col3','col4']].idxmax(axis=1)
0    col3
1    col4
2    col2
3    col1
dtype: object
```

And to assign it to your `df` :

```py
>>> df['result'] = df[['col1','col2','col3','col4']].idxmax(axis=1)
```

You get :

```py
>>> df
    userid  col1    col2    col3    col4    result
0   d1        40      50      75      65      col3
1   d2        54      20      61      71      col4
2   d3        12      75      12      60      col2
3   d4        75      12      14      16      col1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter those columns with numbers using [`.select_dtypes()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and then compare those columns with `x` and get the column name by `.idxmax(axis=1)` across the row, as follows:

(Let's assume `x = 70` below):

```
x = 70           
df2 = df.select_dtypes('number')
df['result'] = (df2 > x).idxmax(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

  userid  col1  col2  col3  col4 result
0     d1    40    50    75    65   col3
1     d2    54    20    61    71   col4
2     d3    12    75    12    60   col2
3     d4    75    12    14    16   col1
```